# How to extract specific information from sentences using NLTK

Tags: python, dependencies, nlp, nltk

I am new using Python and NLTK for NLP operations. Starting with different sentences I was wondering how I can extract certain dependent relations within a sentence.

For example:
*Edward has a black jacket and white shoes with red laces*

Using POS tagging I can extract certain parts of speech, but I want to specifically extract that he has, for example, a black jacket to ultimately list the information like:

**Name:** Edward

**Clothing:** Black jacket

**Shoes:** White shoes with red laces

Comment: Can you show us your code for the POS tagger and the output?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [NER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (Named Entity Recognition) . Since every sentence structure is different and information required from them are different you might need to make your own you get the template or working example from [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html).

There are also huge corpora available which you can use.

Comment: Well it is possible to create my own grammar with regular expressions based on the POS tags, which I am trying at the moment. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the problem as extracting relation tuples, may be as binary relations. In that case you need to know about [open IE](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml). In that case, you can extract relation tuples like,  or . You can build your own relation extraction model if you have supervised data. Otherwise extracting name, clothing or other important information wouldn't be easy using other techniques like NER or POSTagging.

One alternative way can be dependency parsing but i am not sure how to model it for adapting to your particular needs.